# VBA Excel - Find String, Sum Corresponding Value, Variable Locations Across Multiple Sheets; Summing Subtotals in variable locations

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've spent hours trying to write a single excel formula, to no avail. I just decided to write a VBA macro instead, but have very little VBA experience and am having trouble adapting other (similar, but not quite similar enough) answers to my needs.

I have a template workbook used for ordering inventory, with subtotals on each page. I need the Summary sheet to output the total amount (the sum of subtotals from each sheet). A simple test workbook is attached. This is of the form:

> Sheet1
>
> Column [LOCATION1 UNKNOWN] | Next Column
>
> StringOfInterest . . . . . . . . . . . .  . . . .| Value_1
>
> .
>
> Sheet2
>
> Column [LOCATION2 UNKNOWN] | Next Column
>
> StringOfInterest . . . . . . . . . . . .  . . . .| Value_2
>
> .

...

> .
>
> SummarySheet
>
> Column N | Column N=1
>
> StringOfInterest | Value_1+Value_2+...+Value_m

NOTE: Number of sheets change, and StringOfInterest is actually in a merged cell of one row high by two columns wide.

Specific Constraints:
The cells containing the StringOfInterest "Subtotal" and its corresponding value in the adjacent column are in arbitrary locations between each sheet. The "Subtotal" string is actually located on two adjacent column cells merged into a single cell. I CANNOT make any edits to the sheets themselves, except to (1) Add a new sheet if necessary, (2) input the desired total in the Summary sheet.
This will need to be robust to: adding new inventory sheets, deleting old inventory sheets, changing sheet names, and changing the location of a subtotal on any sheet.

It seems like it should be straightforward: Match the string "Subtotal" across all sheets, offset each matched cell by one column (maybe two, depending on how excel handles merged cells), and sum those values.

I have tried to use various combinations of SUM(IF()), SUMIF(), SUMIFS(), SUMPRODUCT(), utilizing INDIRECT(), MATCH(), VLOOKUP(), OFFSET(), among others. To no avail. At this point, I don't mind just giving my supervisor a macro to run that does this calculation and outputs the total into a defined cell on his summary page.

I have included a simplified workbook to explicitly show what I need. Sheet 7, named Summary, has a cell with the string name of interest, and a place to output the total. If needed, I can change the Summary page to avoid having a cell identical to the search string (say, "Subtotals SUMMED" instead of "Subtotal"... or, "hello summed" instead of "hello", in this simplified workbook), and/or I can add a page for placeholders (but it has to be able to respond to potential changes mentioned above, without me making mandatory edits each time)

Thanks for the help!

(Note: Using Excel for Office 365)

EDIT: uploaded file to google sheets since Stack Overflow doesn't support attached files: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RGpQ-4KSYYuwbpWGb0DPAI6qhxLQ0d4CqLwW2gOns2A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the Index() Match() combination formula.

http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/

Try this code snippet it should do what you're looking for:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim myArr() As Variant
Dim rng As Range

'Finds all the cells where "Hello" is found and stores them in an array
ReDim myArr(0)
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With ws.Cells
        Set rng = .Find(What:="Hello", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart _
        , SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            myArr(UBound(myArr)) = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
            ReDim Preserve myArr(UBound(myArr) + 1)
        End If
    End With

Next

'loop through array to sum everything up
For i = 0 To UBound(myArr)
    'do math
Next
```

Comment: Yes. In my primary code, I tried something like `SUM(OFFSET(INDEX(FirstPageName:LastPageName!1:1048576,MATCH("Subtotal",1:1048576,0)),0,1,1,1))` ; The result is a VALUE error, "The Error Tracer encountered existing arrows or a circular reference. Delete all  tracer arrows or resolve the circular reference, and then choose Trace Error again."

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!! If any VBA super-noobs find this, don't forget to start with `Public Sub Arbitrary_Name_Of_Macro()` before the Dim statements, and end with `End Sub` for the last line. I decided to manually insert the results into my "Total" Column in page seven (after changing the entry on row2col1 on page seven from "hello" to "hello total"), by : 
`Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer 
...
iRow = 2
iCol = 2
Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myArr_Tot`

Answer (score 0):

R. Roe gave the perfect solution to my problem, with a very straightforward VBA macro! I made a comment to that answer, but this may be more visible for future Stack Overview lurkers...

If any VBA super-noobs find this, don't forget to start with 
`Public Sub Arbitrary_Name_Of_Macro()` 
before the Dim statements, and end with 
`End Sub` 
for the last line. I decided to manually insert the results into my "Total" Column in page seven (after changing the entry on row2col1 on page seven from "hello" to "hello total"), by :

`Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer 
...
iRow = 2
iCol = 2
Cells(iRow, iCol).Value = myArr_Tot`